# Table with 100 % width and vertical / horizontal alignment

Tags: tables, tabularx

I want to draw the following table in LaTeX. In the first column the text should be left aligned. The text in all other cells should be centered. The first problem occurs with D in the first row. If I write a `\centering` in front of `D`, I get a LaTeX error. The second problem is, that I want to vertically align the text in all cells but I don't know how. I have found a solution but it doesn't work if the width of the first column is specified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{4cm}|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline
               & \centering A & \centering B & \centering C & D\\
    \hline
    \blindtext & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123\\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\arraybackslash` to `\centering` or use `\tabularnewline` instead of ``\\``.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For horizontally and vertically centered text redefine the X column definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}

\newcommand\TEXT{%
I want to draw the following table in Latex. In the first column the text should be left aligned. The text in all other cells should be centered.}% only for demo


\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|m{4cm}*4{|X}|}\hline
           &  A  &   B &   C & D         \\\hline
\TEXT\TEXT & 123 & 123 & 123 & \TEXT\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I want...

Answer (score 6):

You can do the alignment with standard TeX methods but better with LaTeX's `ragged2e` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{ragged2e}


\begin{document}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\RaggedRight}p{4cm}*{5}{|>{\Centering}X}|}
    \hline
               &  A & B & C & D\\
    \hline
    \blindtext & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123\\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

An `X` column is basically a `p{...}` column. Therefore you can use the commands like `\RaggedRight` at the beginning of each cell. To do that automatically for each cell, just use `>{..}`, which inserts the contents of the curly braces at the beginning of each cell in that row.

To avoid the repetition of the last five cells, I have inserted the construct `*{5}{...}`.