# Vertically centered text in tabularx (again)?

Tags: vertical-alignment, line-breaking, tabularx

I have seen [Table with 100 % width and vertical / horizontal alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108442/table-with-100-width-and-vertical-horizontal-alignment), [Vertically center text in tabularx table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104544/vertically-center-text-in-tabularx-table), [Vertical alignment in tabularx X column type](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113020/vertical-alignment-in-tabularx-x-column-type) - and I'm trying what they suggest, but it doesn't work.

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hhline}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]
{>{\raggedright}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{z}[1]
{>{\centering}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}  %% COMMENT

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]%t1
\caption{A rather long explanation of what this table is supposed to be}
\small%
{%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}%
  {|x{2.6cm}|X|}  %% COMMENT
%   {|x{2.6cm}|>{\centering}X|} %% UNCOMMENT
\hline
Something something & something else \tn
\hhline{|=|=|}
\textbf{Item one} \\ {\small\it item ref 1} &%
  param 01 / param 02 \\/ param3\tn
\hline
\textbf{Item two} \\ {\small\it item ref 2} &%
  param 03 / param 04 \\/ param5\tn
\hline
\textbf{Item two} \\ {\small\it item ref 2} &%
  param 03 / param 04 / param5\tn
\hline
\end{tabularx}}
\label{tab:sometable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

As is, this produces:

[image: testc2.png]

... so clearly something is broken (the `\\` are seen as new table lines, I guess)?

But if you uncomment/comment the lines as marked with `%%` in the MWE, it compiles almost fine:

[image: testc1.png]

... except there is no vertical centering - as evidenced by the 3rd row, 2nd column.

So how can I have a column that stretches, that allows line breaking inside a cell - and centers the text vertically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\Centering` tries to be kind and avoids redefining `\\` so `\\` is safe to use in the first column but not the second. this just tells `\Centering` not to worry about the `tabular` version of `\\`.  Unrelated, but don't use `[h!]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hhline}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]
{>{\raggedright}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{z}[1]
{>{\centering}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{%
\let\@raggedtwoe@savedcr\\%
\Centering}m{#1}}  %% COMMENT
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]%t1
\caption{A rather long explanation of what this table is supposed to be}
\small%
{%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}%
  {|x{2.6cm}|X|}  %% COMMENT
%   {|x{2.6cm}|>{\centering}X|} %% UNCOMMENT
\hline
Something something & something else \tn
\hhline{|=|=|}
\textbf{Item one} \\ {\small\it item ref 1} &%
  param 01 / param 02 {\show\\}\\/ param3\tn
\hline
\textbf{Item two} \\ {\small\it item ref 2} &%
  param 03 / param 04 \\/ param5\tn
\hline
\textbf{Item two} \\ {\small\it item ref 2} &%
  param 03 / param 04 / param5\tn
\hline
\end{tabularx}}
\label{tab:sometable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would change the definition of `x` to `\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\raggedright}m{#1}}` to get the cells vertically centered.

Comment: Many thanks @DavidCarlisle - just tried your code as is, but the cells in second column are still not vertically centered [(img)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7W3cq.png); by adding the command by @esdd right before the `\makeatletter`, I finally get vertically centered columns [(img2)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iePn2.png). Thanks again both - cheers!

Comment: Also just a note: it is also possible to use `\raisebox{-0.5em}{text}` etc manually wrapping a cell's content, if there are just a few cells to adjust vertically, without having to load `ragged2e` (or redefine columns for vertical centering).

Comment: @sdaau oh sorry, was concentrating on the `|` the `m` column was centering the second column, so aligning its centre with the reference point of the cell in  first column (its first line), using `m` in both puts the reference points of both cells in their centre.

Comment: @sdaau ragged2e is unrelated to vertical centering.

Comment: thanks for the notes, @DavidCarlisle - good to have them in mind! (also, a note: `\newcolumntype{x}...` causes `Package array Warning: Column x is already defined`). Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau it only gives that warning if you define `x` twice. It does not by default or in this MWE

Answer (score 2):

A variant using `makecell` to have vertically centred cells with line breaks, and `cellspace` to have less tight vertical spacing between rows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hhline}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]
{>{\raggedright}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{z}[1]
{>{\centering}m{#1}}
\newcommand{\tn}{\tabularnewline}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} %% COMMENT
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{2pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{x, }
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]%t1
  \caption{A rather long explanation of what this table is supposed to be}
  \small
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}%
    {|S{x{2.6cm}}|X|} %
    \hline
    \makecell{Something \\something} & something else \\
    \hhline{|=|=|}
    \makecell{\textbf{Item one} \\ {\small\it item ref 1}} &%
    param 01 / param 02 \par/ param3\tn
    \hline
    \makecell{\textbf{Item two} \\ {\small\it item ref 2}} &%
    param 03 / param 04 \par/ param5\tn
    \hline
    \makecell{\textbf{Item two} \\ {\small\it item ref 2}} &%
    param 03 / param 04 / param5\tn
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \label{tab:sometable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]