# Vertically aligned text in only one column in tabularx (again and again)?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I know it is very similar to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113022/vertical-alignment-in-tabular-cells-with-variable-height), [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244174/vertically-centered-text-in-tabularx-again), and others... but with 3 columns I have not been able to apply the solutions. I would like the two first columns (where I actually have a lot of text, of different length) to be top aligned, while the last column to be vertically centered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | X | X | c | }
  \hline
  bla\newline bla \newline   & bla\newline bla \newline  & top\\
  \hline
  bla\newline bla \newline bla \newline  & \noindent\parbox[c]{\hsize}{ bla\newline bla \newline }  & center\\
  \hline
  bla\newline bla \newline & \noindent\parbox[b]{\hsize}{bla\newline bla \newline }   &  bottom\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  can do that with `multirow` by trial and error, counting the maximal number of lines in cells of the current row. I added the `makecell`package to have a simpler syntax with `multirowcell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | X | X | c | }
  \hline
  bla\newline bla \newline & bla\newline bla \newline &\multirowcell{3}{top}\\
  \hline
  bla\newline bla \newline bla \newline & bla\newline bla \newline & \multirowcell{4}{center}\\
  \hline
  bla\newline bla \newline & bla\newline bla \newline & \multirowcell{3}{bottom}\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see, I thought there would be something more 'automatic', like a new column definition. Seeing your number of points though, I think this is the best solution :)

Comment: I don't know everything about LaTeX! If there is is an automatic solution, or if it is possible to define one, I don't know it.